# When importing MP3 data, some images appear blank and give the warning I wrote below, as a result of which the application slows down a lot

Tags: android, flutter, mp3

warning = E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(21416): getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.
Lost connection to device.

```
Future<void> fetchMusic() async {
   _audioQuery = OnAudioQuery();
 _musicList = await _audioQuery.querySongs(
      sortType: SongSortType.DATE_ADDED,
      orderType: OrderType.DESC_OR_GREATER,
      uriType: UriType.EXTERNAL,
      ignoreCase: true,

 );
_musicList.forEach((element)async {
  var media = await _audioQuery.queryArtwork(element.id, ArtworkType.AUDIO);
   if(media == null){
       _musicList.removeAt(element.id); 
   }
 });
  notifyListeners();
}
```

E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(21416): How can I block the warning?